# What font does Notepad++ use to display windows arabic in windows-1256 characters?

Tags: windows-7, video, dvd, vlc-media-player, subtitles

I’m trying to display closed captioning on the movie "The Terminal" with Tom Hanks. I went to a website that has subtitles for the movie in `.srt` format and downloaded them. I added them to VLC media player (64-bit) on Windows 7.

I also changed some settings in VLC while the movie is playing:

1. I added the captions file (`.srt`)  `Subtitle->Add Subtitle File...`
2. `Tools->Preferences`
3. In the `Simple Preferences` dialog I clicked `Subtitles / OSD`
4. From the `Default Encoding` drop down I selected `Arabic (Windows-1256)`
5. Clicked `OK`

The sub-titles displayed somewhat correctly, but not entirely; a few of the characters were missing in the subtitles.

So I downloaded Notepad++ and opened the `.srt` file containing the Arabic subtitles.

To get that file to display correctly, from the menu I had to click `Encoding -> Charactersets ->  Arabic-> Windows-1256`

In Notepad++ it appears to display all of the characters correctly.  The only setting I can think of that might need to be changed here is back in VLC, in the `Subtitles / OSD` settings; and that is the `font`.

So my question is, what font does Notepad++ use to display the Arabic character set `Arabic (Windows-1256)`?

I found a font setting that said it the font was `Courier New`, but upon setting that same setting to this font in VLC the problem with some of the characters not displaying is still occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So my question is, what font does notepad++ use to display the Arabic
>   character set Arabic (Windows-1256)?

It might be that Notepad++ is converting `Windows-1256` to `UTF-8` on the fly within it’s code for display purposes. The big clue to me is when you say this:

> I found a font setting that said it the font was Courier New…

Courier New should be a UTF-8 character set. So one idea to solve the issue is to open the file in Notepad++ and then convert it to UTF-8 via the “file format” menu and save the new file. That way the file and its contents will now be UTF-8 which is pretty much the most digestible encoding standard for extended character set processing.

Another idea comes from [this issue report on the official VLC developer’s bug tracker](https://trac.videolan.org/vlc/ticket/7990); emphasis mine:

> After installing windows 8 ,  the Arabic subtitle appear like squares
>   even after changing the encoding to windows-1256 same problem on
>   another device with win 8  VLC 2.0.4 or 2.0.5, same issue MPC Player
>   show the arabic subtitle immediately, without adjusting the encoding
>   too **the only fix I found is to change the default font "Arial" to an
>   arabic font, "Traditional Arabic" Font is clear and nice and all
>   characters are perfect note: windows 8 has change the default arabic
>   font in general**

Looking [at this answer on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/147433) it seems a potential solution lies in using the Tahoma font:

> Go to VLC:
>
> 1. Click Tools and next Preferences
> 2. Click Subtitle & OSD
> 3. In section Subtitle Language and Default encoding
> 4. Select Arabic (Windows-1256)
> 5. In section font select the Tahoma font

Comment: To add to your notes here; and it did work by the way...if you want it to sync up; you have to start the movie from the first track of film; pause the movie; move it all the way back to 00:00; add the subtitles; and then start the film.

Comment: Both.  There are still a few missing characters, but it isn't too bad.